# Serilog with .net 5 for windows form

Tags: serilog

I'm using serilog, it is working well for net core.  However, it doesn't seem to work with latest ne5 5 preview, any ideas?  I am using winForm

Comment: What does your code look like, what errors are you seeing, what troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: Not much, All I was doing was just adding net5.0 to targetFrameworks in csproj. I got the following error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB3644 The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks Serilog C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.target

Comment: That error is not specific to Serilog

Comment: You can take a look at this. I have tried it, but I believe it will help